# How to start WMI Service from installer code?

Tags: c#, wmi

In visual studio Code using WMI events like

```
WqlEventQuery query = new WqlEventQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM RegistryKeyChangeEvent WHERE " +
               "Hive = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE'" +
              @"AND KeyPath = 'HARDWARE\\DEVICEMAP\\SERIALCOMM'");

            registryWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(managementScope, query);
```

Some of PC are WMI event service are stopped manually or automatically, When I installing How to start this service from My code?

Comment: Is RPC enabled on those hosts? If so then you can call the native Windows command line function SC to control services on any Windows computer you have admin rights on which also has RPC enabled (i.e., not firewalled).